# Can't create MS SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger, sql-server-2019

I'm experiencing unexpected behaviour in my database.

I'm trying to create a trigger, and getting the error that it already exist:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 2, Procedure xxxx_xxxxx_INSERT, Line 2
> [Batch Start Line 0] There is already an object named
> 'xxxx_xxxxx_INSERT' in the database.

However, I don't see a trigger with this name (below is the query I used to check), and I can't find it via the management studio either.

```
select a.[name] as trgname, 
       b.[name] as [tbname] 
from sys.triggers a 
join sys.tables b on a.parent_id = b.object_id
order by trgname
```

What else can I check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces are confusing and not well documented in SQL Server.

In your case, there will be another schema-scoped *object* in the database with the same identifier as the one you are hoping to use for your trigger.

My guess would be there is a stored procedure with the same name.

You can check schema-scoped objects in the [`sys.objects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql) system view.